# Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'User Error some transactions...'

Tags: php, save, data

I'm getting this error when i try to save to my db an employee.

```
> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'User Error:
> Some trans actions have not been committed or rolled back in
> C:\wamp64\www\magento1\vendor\
> magento\framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php on line 3774' in
> C:\wamp64\www\magent
> o1\vendor\magento\framework\App\ErrorHandler.php:61 Stack trace:
> #0 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(256, 'Some t
> ransactio...', 'C:\\wamp64\\www\\m...', 3774, Array)
> #1 C:\wamp64\www\magento1\vendor\magento\framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(3774
> ): trigger_error('Some transactio...', 256)
> #2 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->__destruct()
> #3 {main}   thrown in C:\wamp64\www\magento1\vendor\magento\framework\App\ErrorHandler.php 
> on line 61
```

Here is the code

```
public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context) {
        $setup->startSetup();

        $salesDepartment = $this->departmentFactory->create();
        $salesDepartment->setName('Sales');
        $salesDepartment->save();


        $employee = $this->employeeFactory->create();
        $employee->setDepartmentId($salesDepartment->getId())
            ->setEmail('john@sales.loc')
            ->setFirstName('John')
            ->setLastName('Doe')
            ->setServiceYears(3)
            ->setDob('1983-03-28')
            ->setSalary(3800.00)
            ->setVatNumber('GB123456789')
            ->setNote('Example note!')
            ->save();

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

The sales department has been saved to database though.